# with distutils, how know if data dir path are setted by user

Tags: python, distutils

I would like wrap distutils for get data dir, because user can change this path so in my project somewhere i have a variable with hardcoded path ie:

```
SQL_FILE        = os.path.join(sys.prefix, "share/bbcf/database/bbcf.sql")
```

i do not want use package data
i want just take the data dir and do something like :

```
sed 's/SQL_FILE        = os.path.join(sys.prefix, \"share/bbcf/database/bbcf.sql\")/ <the new data dir>/' the_module.py
```

thanks for your help

Comment: @bioinformatics, distutil == distutils ? I can not understand the relation of the question title with the question text. Seems you are asking two different things...

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Yes i talk about distutils. in my setup.py i have something like: data_files = [( "share/bbcf/database/", glob.glob("data/bbcf.sql") )]  ... So if a user choose alternate path SQL_FILE will never found where is the file